# How can I fetch XML data with RTK Query?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm already using RTK Query with different endpoints that return JSON which are working as expected. But there is one endpoint that returns XML. I can see in the network tab that HTTP response is correct but RTK Query's auto generated hook returns `data` as `undefined`.

Here's is my query definition:

```js
import { myApi } from './base';

export const excel = myApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchExcelUserList: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: 'excel/user_list',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset:utf-8',
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useFetchExcelUserListQuery } = excel;
```

That's how I use it:

```js
  const { data } = useFetchExcelQuery('');
  console.log(data);
```

If this explanation isn't enough, check [this link](https://serveanswer.com/questions/rtk-query-doesnt-parse-data) that describes the same problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is `undefined`, because your query goes into an error state - by default, everything will be parsed as json. You can provide a custom parsing function using the [`responseHandler`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response) functionality of `fetchaseQuery` though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry that I didn't catch that on documentation. Next time I'll be more careful.